# Distributing list items to variables in clojure

Tags: clojure

When I pass this function

```
(into [] 
      (map #(+ %1 %2)
           [1 2]
           [5 6]))
```

I get this result: `[6 8]`

What should I do to get this: `[6 7 7 8]` while keeping this `#(+ %1 %2)` ?

Seems like `map` isn't the right function in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `for` when you want a Cartesian product:

```
user=> (for [x [1 2] y [5 6]]
  #_=>   (+ x y))
(6 7 7 8)
```

Answer (score 2):

`for` is one option as Alex answer shows. `map` can also be used (with `mapcat`) as shown below:

```
user=> (mapcat #(map (partial + %1) [5 6]) [1 2])
(6 7 7 8)
```

Comment: In what situation would you use `mapcat` / `map` over `for` ?

Comment: `for` is a macro whereas `mapcat` and `map` are functions, so you cannot use `for` in many scenarios like function composition etc