# Clojure: for for n Dimensions

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

In Clojure the function `for` can be used for iterating nested sequences. Imagine a 3D space with a x-, y- and z-axis:

```
(for [x (range 10)
      y (range 5)
      z (range 2)]
    [x y z])
```

The code above would produce a sequence of vectors which represents all possible positions inside a cuboid. (limited to the positions which indices are natural numbers of course)

Does anybody know a good way to make this more generic? Meaning, to make it work if you have not a number of 3 but of n dimensions.

Answer (score 5):

[Most](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036460/distributing-list-items-to-variables-in-clojure/15036580) [approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646544/clojure-how-do-i-get-a-list-of-combinations-of-coordinates/1646787) seem to use `for`, as you do, assuming a known number of dimensions. What you seem to be looking for is the [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). There is a function for calculating cartesian products in [clojure.math.combinatorics](https://github.com/clojure/math.combinatorics).

```
(cartesian-product (range 10) (range 5) (range 2))
(apply cartesian-product (map range [10 5 2]))
(apply cartesian-product (repeatedly n #(range 3)))
```

If you don't want to include another library, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246549/cartesian-product-in-clojure) has some interesting answers which you can use and/or learn from.

---

As of March 2016, this was the source for `clojure.math.combinatorics/cartesian-product`:

```
(defn cartesian-product
  "All the ways to take one item from each sequence"
  [& seqs]
  (let [v-original-seqs (vec seqs)
        step
        (fn step [v-seqs]
          (let [increment
                (fn [v-seqs]
                  (loop [i (dec (count v-seqs)), v-seqs v-seqs]
                    (if (= i -1) nil
                      (if-let [rst (next (v-seqs i))]
                        (assoc v-seqs i rst)
                            (recur (dec i) (assoc v-seqs i (v-original-seqs i)))))))]
            (when v-seqs
              (cons (map first v-seqs)
                    (lazy-seq (step (increment v-seqs)))))))]
    (when (every? seq seqs)
      (lazy-seq (step v-original-seqs)))))
```

Comment: can I use clojure.math.combinatorics with ClojureScript? I don't find documentation for this..

Comment: @AntonHarald: I don't know about the whole library. You can use the function in question, though.

Comment: interesting algorithm, finally grasped it... true, I can just implement this function. looks like until now only the "Clojure contrib libraries" are supported which are listed right here: https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Differences-from-Clojure

Answer (score 1):

another way to do it (probably worse then a `cartesian-product`, but still nice to show the power of clojure's macros):

```
(defmacro product [& colls]
  (let [names (repeatedly (count colls) #(gensym "var"))]
    `(for ~(vec (interleave names colls))
       ~(vec names))))
```

it just generates this `for` list comprehension for any number of colls. for example:

```
(product (range 3) [:a :b :c] (range 2))
```

would expand into the following:

```
(for [var19715 (range 3) var19716 [:a :b :c] var19717 (range 2)]
  [var19715 var19716 var19717])
```

Comment: The downside to this, of course, is that you still have to know how many dimensions there are up front. I.e., since it's not a macro, you can't do something like `(apply product (map range dim-sizes))`. 

That is, unless you use `eval`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`for` is a macro and its body expression can contain arbitrary code, such as a `do` block or IO calls:

```
(for [x (range 3)]
  (do
    (prn x)
    x))
```

Assuming the desired body expression is always in the form of `[x y z ... n]` and the inputs are positive ranges

#### How to create a sequence of positions of an n dimensional matrix:

```
(defn matrix [h & t]
  (if (some? t)
    (for [d (range h)
          ds (apply matrix t)]
      (into [d] ds))
    (map vector (range h))))
```

It is somewhat naive, but seems to do the job:

```
(matrix 3) ;; => (map vector (range 3))
;; => ([0] [1] [2])

(matrix 3 2) ;; => (for [d (range 3) ds (apply matrix '(2))] (into [d] ds))
;; => ([0 0] [0 1] [1 0] [1 1] [2 0] [2 1])

(matrix 3 2 4)
;; => ([0 0 0] [0 0 1] [0 0 2] [0 0 3] [0 1 0] [0 1 1] [0 1 2] [0 1 3] 
;;     [1 0 0] [1 0 1] [1 0 2] [1 0 3] [1 1 0] [1 1 1] [1 1 2] [1 1 3] 
;;     [2 0 0] [2 0 1] [2 0 2] [2 0 3] [2 1 0] [2 1 1] [2 1 2] [2 1 3])
```

---

I said naive because `for` is lazy but `into` is eager. Wrapping `for` with `doall` would force evaluation but a `loop` using transients can probably perform better.